# Grep search from end of file

Tags: bash

I have large log file 300-500 megs and need to do searches in it. I am currently doing this using grep in php code, but I want to further optimize the code.
Data I need is always within last 10000 lines in the file so I want the search to start from the end and move forward until pattern is found and stop.

I found some info that tac can do this but my performance tests show using tac is 4 times slower.
Currently my search takes about 0.13 sec to complete with tac added on it takes 0.50. I feel like I am missing something, I would appreciate help.

My expectation is that if I get file read from the end properly this will increase the speed of the process considerably.

here is the code and it includes the timer

```
<?php
exec('grep -r "search var" file.log -b  | head -1', $result);
echo $result[0];

$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
echo "<br>".$time; 
?>
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the `-r` flag with `grep`. And you only want to search within the last 10000 lines right? So directly `tail` it and `grep` the pattern.

```
tail file.log -n 10000 | grep "search var"
```

Comment: Tail code for 1000 lines looks to be the solution. My initial tests on 350meg file returns results in 0.0045490 seconds. I don't think file size will make much of a difference with that. I will use that approach in next build and let you know how it work out. Thank you very much